# How to make if else work for python3

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have recently made the switch to Python 3 and regular things that usually work with Python 2 don't work with Python 3. I have been able to fix the rest but I am struggling with this one. I cannot check what "type" something is.

```
raw = input("Please give me a number, string\
 or decimal: ")
if type(raw) == int:
    print("You entered a number")
elif type(raw) == float:
    print("You entered a decimal")
elif type(raw) == str:
    print("You entered a string")
else:
    print("error please try again")
```

`

Comment: it should be you entered a string :) am I right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In python3.x, `input` always returns an object of type `str`.  The equivalent to python2.x would be `eval(input('...'))`.  As with using `eval` at any time, be sure that you absolutely trust that the input won't do malicious things to your program or computer...

A *better* way would be to use something like `ast.literal_eval` (which will safely evaluate your literals) or to do the checking yourself...

```
def is_int_str(s):
    """Checks if a string (s) represents a python integer."""
    try:
        int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

And it's trivial to then write the analogous `float` version...

Comment: there are isdigit/isnumeric methods in the string library that should probably be used here.

Comment: @story645 -- Nah... EAFP :-).  Just `try` to convert the string to the appropriate type and see if it works ...

Comment: meh, I like the string library for this...but really, just anything that isn't eval is probably good.